# Не работает Controller

Tags: java, spring, mvc, spring-mvc

Не работают REST запросы, те при переходе на http://localhost:8080/ появляется HTTP Status 404 – Not Found, хотя я ожидаю увидеть табличку с данными из таблицы БД
MainController.java:

```
package com.NGTUProj.GS.Controller;
import ...
@RestController
@ComponentScan("com.NGTUProj.GS")
public class MainController {
    private final ClientService clientService;

    public MainController(ClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("clients", clientService.getAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/client/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createClient(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("email") String email, @RequestParam("telephone") String telephone) {
        clientService.addClient(new ClientEntity(name, email, telephone));
        return "redirect :/";
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

<display-name>GameShop</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

spring-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Конфигурация Spring -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.NGTUProj.GS"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/View/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>`

    <!-- Настройка подключения к БД -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gameshop?useSSL=false"
          p:user="root"
          p:password="password"
    />

    <bean id = "entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.NGTUProj.GS.Entity" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="item-manager-pu"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.NGTUProj.GS.Repository"/>
</beans>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <title>GameShop</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

    <div id="dialog">
            <br><br><table>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>telephone</th>
                <th>orders</th>
              </tr>
              <c:forEach items="${clients}" var="client" varStatus="status">
                <tr valign="top">
                  <td>${client.getName()}</td>
                  <td>${client.getEmail()}</td>
                  <td>${client.getTelephone()}</td>
                  <td><a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/get_orders_by_id?id=?${client.id}">list orders</a>
                </tr>
              </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Структура проекта: 
(класс Main никак не учавствует, нужен был только для проверки Entity, запускается через TomCat, Application Context: /)**

[image: структура проекта]

Comment: Где настройки dispatcherServlet и Security?

Comment: куда вы деплоите приложение? если ничего специально не настраивали, то путь должен быть `http://localhost:8080/имя_вашего_приложения`

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap model) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: пробовал, к сожалению результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

Замените аннотацию @RestController на @Controller

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема была, долго не мог понять в чем проблема, просто папка webapp должна быть в папке main.